# Angular: Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am receiving an issue with my added Trustbox component ts file in the command line after serving my app.

```
    "Property 'Trustpilot' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."
```

I have tried to declare the window and searched far and wide for a solution to this but for the life of me can not figure it out.

Here is the trustbox.component.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-trustbox',
  templateUrl: './trustbox.component.html',
})
export class TrustboxComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const trustboxRef = document.getElementById('trustbox');
    window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(trustboxRef);
  }
}
```

According to Trustpilot article (https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011421468--Add-a-TrustBox-widget-to-a-single-page-application) to get their widget working on a SPA you must

1. Implement OnInit.
2. Get a reference to the element that we pasted previously.
3. Call the loadFromElement function.

I know this is something probably very simple but it is extremely annoying as I can't compile my application. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use @[ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild), to get the references and work on them, and use AfterViewInit to use only after the reader is done and the component is created on the screen.

Example:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <p #pRef>
      Start editing to see some magic happen :)
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = "Angular";

  @ViewChild("pRef", { static: false }) pRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "DOM updated succesfully!!!";
  }
}
```